# Why my CSS code can't make the background color for the table?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to highlight my table background color as blue. But my code isn't working.

***index.php class***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<table class="tb">
<tr><td>first row</td></tr>
<tr><td>second row</td></tr>
<tr><td>third row</td></tr>

</table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selector.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

***style.css class:***

```
    .tb,.tb tr,.tb td{
border: 1px solid red;
}
.highlight{
background-color: blue;
}
```

***table.js class:***

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.tb').addClass('highlight');
});
```

My folders paths are the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery\style.css ; 
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery\js\jquery.js ;
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery\js\table.js ;
C:\xampp\htdocs\jquery\index.php;
```

Comment: if your using jquery wheres jquery.min.js??

Comment: include jquery library file in your page.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqry.js"></script>` jquery file spelt wrong

Comment: This code works as expected for me, meaning that the problem is probably due to your mis-spelling of the word jQuery in your script link, or the fact that you haven't included table.js in the page at all [Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a8eM/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be like this...

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
```

I think you forgot to call the table.js.

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery is not working as you are not including it correctly. Therefore it nevers gets assigned the class `highlight`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqry.js"></script>
```

Has a typo. Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And you need to add

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/table.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using normal css rules like this:

```
.tb { background-color: color; }
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/55tye/

You dont need JS / jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `table.js` included in your `index.php` file?

Because I can't see it in provided code?

Please verify after adding that file in your code. and see it its working or not!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I could argue that it does provide a partial answer if the js code wasn't included in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.tb,.tb tr,.tb td{
border: 1px solid red !Important;
}
.highlight{
background: blue !Important;
}
```